# HttpRequestInterceptor display multiples times the same error

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors, angular-toastr

I added a `HttpRequestInterceptor` insie my AngularJS app to display a [toastr](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr) every time a request fails.

```
angular.module('spwApp.factories')
    .factory('httpRequestInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector', '$cookies', '$rootScope', function($q, $injector, $cookies, $rootScope) {
        return {
            'request': function($config) {
                var token = $cookies.get('token');
                $config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
                return $config;
            },
            'responseError': function(rejection) {
                var toastr = $injector.get('toastr');
                var $state = $injector.get('$state');
                toastr.options = {
                    "closeButton" : true,
                    "preventDuplicates" : true,
                    "timeOut": "50000",
                    "extendedTimeOut" : "50000"
                };
                toastr.remove();
                switch (rejection.status) {
                    case 401:
                        if ($state.current.name != 'login') {
                            $state.go('login');
                            toastr.info('Re-enter username/password', 'Invalid sessions', toastr.options);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 403:
                        toastr.error('You do not have the rights', 'Forbidden', toastr.options)
                        $state.go('home');
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        toastr.error('Cannot found', '??', toastr.options);
                        $state.go('home');
                        break;
                    case 500:
                        toastr.error('Unexpected error', 'Hum...', toastr.options);
                        $state.go('home');
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        toastr.error('Connection to server not possible', 'Ouch...', toastr.options);
                        $state.go('home');
                        break;
                    default:
                        toastr.error('That is not supposed to land here', 'Oops...', toastr.options);
                        $state.go('home');
                        break;
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

On certain page, I have to resolve multiple data from my server

```
.state('stateA', {
    url: '/urlToStateA',
    views: {
        'content@stateA': {
            templateUrl: 'app/stateA.html',
            controller: 'controllerA',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                dataA: ['myService', function(myService) {
                    return myService.getDataA();
                }],
                dataB: ['myService', function(myService) {
                    return myService.getDataB();
                }],
                dataC: ['myService', function(myService) {
                    return myService.getDataC();
                }]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Thus when my server is turned off, each request will get a `rejection.status == -1` and then display the toastr `Connection to server not possible`

The problem is that the line `toastr.remove();` does not work. It is supposed to remove all the toastr but does nothing.

How can I remove the toastr before adding a new one ? Can I replace the non-working `toastr.remove()` with some pure javascript to manually select and remove the toastr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make some `configuration changes` to prevent more `toastr's` opening simultaneously.

The `toastr configurations` can be changed in `config` function of angular.

```
myApp.config(Config);

  function Config($httpProvider,toastrConfig) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('interceptorService');

    angular.extend(toastrConfig, {
       autoDismiss: false,
       containerId: 'toast-container',
       maxOpened: 0,    
       newestOnTop: true,
       positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
       preventDuplicates: false,
       preventOpenDuplicates: true,
       target: 'body'
    });

  }
```

**`preventOpenDuplicates: true`** this line will prevent the same message from displaying multiple times.

From  [**Customizing the toastr link reference**](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr#toastr-customization)

- **autoDismiss:** If set, show only the most recent maxOpened toast(s)
- **containerId:** The name of the container where you want to append your toasts (the container will be created for you).
- **maxOpened:** Maximum number of toasts displayed at once.
- **newestOnTop:** Add new toasts on top of the old one. Put on false to put them on the bottom.
- **positionClass:** The position where the toasts are added.
- **preventDuplicates:** Prevent duplicates of the last toast.
- **preventOpenDuplicates:** Prevent duplicates of open toasts.
- **target:** The element to put the toastr container.